# If I need to use IIFE, why doesn't Angular use it?

Tags: angularjs

In [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)'s style guide he mentions the need to wrap every component in `(function(){..})`. This adds a couple lines to my code which makes me worried but not enough to justify a long work-around.

However, when I look at the actual Angular Code like the code for [$compile](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js) and controller, I don't see these declarations.

Why is it important for me to isolate my variables with IIFE if Ng doesn't see it as important? Or a better question is why doesn't Angular implement IIFE?

Comment: Why? To avoid polluting the global scope and potentially doing something silly. Why doesn't ng do this? Well, it does with its *own* code--why doesn't it *force* you to? Because there's no reason to force you to: we're big boys, we can take care of ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does use IIFE it wraps the code in

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {'use strict';
...

})(window, document);
```

So this distinguishes and protects the global/outer context and environment as a whole for all angular code

You can verify [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js)

> So it is wrapping the entire app right? But it isn't wrapping the
>   individual components

To answer your question, these components are not in separate files and are contained in single IIFE

the separate modules like `angular-route`, `ng-resource` are separated with `angular.module()` namespace or modular pattern from the global context

Comment: So it is wrapping the entire app right? But it isn't wrapping the individual components which is what is suggested by John. If I wrapped my entire app that would be considered wrong according to issues like this...

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/262

 Or https://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/

Comment: So in other words ngRepeat could "technically" pollute say ngBind's variables (if there was a bug)

Comment: Have tried to answer your queries, see updated answer

Comment: Right I get all that so If I have an app why should I isolate every directive like the second link references? Why can't I isolate them just by using angular.module as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be, it depends.

First of all, AngularJS has to expose `angular` for the user to use, so it cannot be inside an IIFE.  (just like jQuery exposes `$` and `jQuery`, although it has an option that it only exposes `jQuery`).

And then, if you do decide to go with AngularJS, it won't be surprising that AngularJS expose some other stuff to the global space.  But so far I have used AngularJS, I have only seen `angular` being exposed and all the things I do, I do it as

```
angular.module()
    .controller()
    .directive()
    .factory()
    .service();
```

and `$compile` is not exposed to the global space.

You only use IIFE to create a local scope so that the variables will not become part of the global scope.